# Proof of definite to indefinite integral transformation problem

Tags: integration

I'd like to prove

If $f(x)$ is continuous, then
$$\int^a_b f(x) \mathrm{d}x=\int f(a) \mathrm{d}a - \int f(b) \mathrm{d}b$$
The problem is that my math teacher uses this "fact" in the proof of one-dimensional constant variation theorem(ODE chapter), here is a piece of his formulation:

...then the solution of equation $y'(x)=a(x)y(x)+b(x)$ is in a form of $$y(x)=e^{A(x_0)-A(x)}y_0+\int_{x_0}^{x}e^{A(t)-A(x)}b(t)\mathrm{d}t$$ where $A(x)=\int a(x)\mathrm{d}x$...

He does not prove it, just states that it is true.
Well, not specificly, but states that $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\int_{x_0}^xf(t)\mathrm{d}t=f(x)$$
which implies, that 
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\int_{x_0}^x f(t)\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(\int f(x)\mathrm{d}x-\int f(x_0)\mathrm{d}(whatever\, is\, not\, x\, and\, makes\, this \,constant))=f(x)$$

Could you please help me, I have no clue how to prove it.

Comment: This is an immediate consequence of the [fundamental theorem of calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Formal_statements).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the meaning is this

$$
\int_b^a f(x) d x = F(a) - F(b)
$$

And we can write

$$
F(x) = \int f(x) dx
$$

so

$$
F(a) = \int f(a) da
$$

and

$$
F(b) = \int f(b) db
$$

thus

$$
\int_b^a f(x) d x = \int f(a) da - \int f(b) db
$$

---

As for the second equations

$$
\frac{d}{dx} \int_{x_0}^x f(t) dt = \frac{d}{dx} \Big( F(x) - F(x_0) \Big) = f(x)
$$

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I figured that out while cooking, that it is a fomal problem and can be easily avoided with defining $F'(x)=f(x)$. I need to cook more :) Thanks anyway.

Comment: This is wrong. You can't simply convert a definite integral to a difference of indefinite integrals like this. The correct way to write this would've been $$\int_b^a f(x)dx = \int_0^a f(x)dx - \int_0^b f(x)dx$$

Comment: Well - it is consistent with the definitions as

$$F(a) = \int f(a) da$$

and

$$F(b) = \int f(b) db$$

Comment: If I can't do that, then the theorem is wrong, because the fact it is true proves that you CAN do the conversion and if this theorem is wrong, then the fundamental theorem of calculus is wrong, because the theorem can prove this theorem. So basically, what you are saying is, that calculus is wrong. And you used calculus to say that calculus is wrong, hence you contradict yourself, so your statement is false and I can convert definite integral into two indefinite integrals.

Comment: if $\int^a_b f(x) \mathrm{d}x\neq\int f(a) \mathrm{d}a - \int f(b) \mathrm{d}b$, then $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\int_{x_0}^x f(t)\mathrm{d}t$ can't be equal to $f(x)$, so this theorem does not hold, since this theorem and the conversion is equivalent to each other and truth of this theorem implies this conversion. I don't care about proper way or "beautiful way" or "unsloppy" way to write it, I am good with true way to prove it and it has to be true way, since the theorem is true.